# WebMatrix 2 - msbuild execution

Tags: webmatrix, webmatrix-2

Is it possible to execute a target in an msbuild script from within webmatrix and have output parsed for errors in MSBuild format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment to the answer of Yishai I wrote the functionality myself. It is open source and available as a NuGet package. Have a look at http://macawnl.github.com/WebMatrix.Executer/.

Some screenshots:
[image: The Output pane]
[image: The Errors & Warnings pane]

It is as easy as one initialization call and you can start executing any command or PowerShell script.

Let me know what you think of it!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. WebMatrix doesn't support running msbuild or feeding errors into the error list.

However, WebMatrix 2.0 introduced an extensibility model, and some of the team members are working on a console extension, this will allow you to run any command line from within WebMatrix (but still not parse and show results).

Another approach could be to write a full extension that will run the msbuild script, there is support to add tabs to the task tabs, where you can create for example a build error tab, and feed the errors there.

Here are some links for reference:
[Defining a task tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.webmatrix.extensibility.tasktabitemdescriptor%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
, [Adding a task tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.webmatrix.extensibility.editor.ieditortaskpanelservice%28v=vs.111%29)

Note that to get access to the task tab you will need to import it through MEF in your extension class, something like the following code:

```
[Import(typeof(IEditorTaskPanelService))]
IEditorTaskPanelService TaskPanelService {get; set;}
```

Comment: Hi Yishai, I wrote the extension myself already. I can run any program, the output of the program is captured to an output pane, and the output is parsed for errors or warnings based on the msbuild warning and error format. I will publish this extension soon as a nuget package.

Comment: Serge this is great! I can wait to see it on the gallery